# How do I make a field that has a hierarchy, such as the product category field of the product model?

Tags: odoo

I would like to create a field that has several categories of professions (parent elements) and at the end the profession corresponding to that category appears, as in the product category field of the product model.

How can I do this?

Comment: Simple solution: like the product category? ;-) In the end it's a new model with a parent-child-relation in it. This relation is implemented by a many2one field on itself usually named `parent_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a computed field that shows the parent categories' names and set it as the `_rec_name` to let Odoo use it as a [display name](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a7f7233e0eae8ee101d745a9813cba930fd03dcb/odoo/models.py#L1834-L1853) in the Many2one fields.

***Example:***

```
class ProfessionCategory(models.Model):
    _name = "profession.category"
    _description = "Profession Category"
    _rec_name = 'complete_name'


    name = fields.Char('Name', index=True, required=True)
    complete_name = fields.Char(
        'Complete Name', compute='_compute_complete_name', recursive=True,
        store=True)
    parent_id = fields.Many2one('profession.category', 'Parent Category', index=True, ondelete='cascade')

    @api.depends('name', 'parent_id.complete_name')
    def _compute_complete_name(self):
        for category in self:
            if category.parent_id:
                category.complete_name = '%s / %s' % (category.parent_id.complete_name, category.name)
            else:
                category.complete_name = category.name
```